# Laravel 4 - Eloquent mass assignment creates empty records after update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mass-assignment, eloquent

I've just updated L4 (both skeleton and packages) to the latest version.

Now, when I try to create a new instance of one of the Models and save it to the DB, I get an empty record, except for the timestamps and the primary key.

This behaviour persists over all models (Users, Bids, Projects etc...) so It's not a local problem.

I tried both

```
Project::create($project);
```

and, [following this thread](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=5824):

```
$new_project = new Project;

$new_project->fill($project);

$new_project->save();
```

But the result is the same: an empty record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as it turns out from the [docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment) Mass assignment is now blocked by default for security reasons (e.g fetching all data from the form without specifying the fields (`Input::all()`) and saving it as is to the DB might result in unwanted fields being assigned, in case the client manipulates the form by adding a field with a name that corresponds to the field in the DB).

To designate the fields that are allowed to be assigned, one should either explicitly add the fields in question as a *white-list* to a protected `$fillable` array on the model, or alternatively, create a *black-list* using the `$guarded` array

Comment: To implement this put protected $fillable = array(); in your model.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem and found solution hope help others

```
$new_project = new Project;

$new_project->unguard();

$new_project->create($project);

$new_project->reguard();


or

Project::unguard();
$new_project = Project::create($project);
$new_project->reguard();
```

Comment: Use the guarded/fillable attribute, you've completely removed the security of mass assignment here!

Comment: yes i am following guarded/fillable attributes now as you can see its an old post.